# Divide X axis by Clickable Zones in HIghchart

Tags: html, highcharts

I want to implement range wise xAxis in Area Graph in highchart.

Zones should be clickable and that should filter the Area in Graph.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the line below your chart, you can use `xAxis` with proper options, but to add the custom labels, you will need to use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks,
                customLabels = ['total: 13', 'Zone of Mediocrity', 'Stocks: 47', 'Good, not great', 'total: 13', 'Zone of "Greatness"'],
                counter = 0,
                xPos,
                tickPos;

            addEvents.call(this);

            Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(el) {
                if (tickPos) {
                    xPos = tickPos.x + (el.mark.getBBox().x - tickPos.x) / 2;
                    drawCustomLabel.call(
                        this,
                        customLabels[counter],
                        xPos,
                        tickPos.y + 10
                    );

                    drawCustomLabel.call(
                        this,
                        customLabels[counter + 1],
                        xPos,
                        tickPos.y + 30
                    );

                    counter += 2;
                }

                tickPos = el.mark.getBBox();
                el.mark.attr({
                    translateY: 7.5
                });
            }, this);
        }
    }
}
```

To divide divide the chart series into several elements use `zones`. The `click` event can be added in this way:

```
function addEvents() {
    var series = this.series[0];

    series['zone-area-0'].element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('zone-area-0');
    });

    ...
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e619th3c/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.areaspline.zones

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if I want to get an event when we click xAxis label Line("Goods, Not great ")

Comment: Hi Vishu238, You only need to add the event to the rendered `text` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82dxv03q/